# Firestore - get specific document based on the field?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

```
 mFirestore.collection("FeaturedDeal").whereEqualTo("title","Amazon India").limit(10).orderBy("priority", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error : " + e.getMessage());

                }

                    assert documentSnapshots != null;
                    for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                        if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                            String doc_id = doc.getDocument().getId();
                            FeaturedDeal featuredDeal = doc.getDocument().toObject(FeaturedDeal.class).withDocId(doc_id);
                            featuredDeals.add(featuredDeal);
                            featuredDealAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED) {
                            String docID = doc.getDocument().getId();
                            FeaturedDeal changedModel = doc.getDocument().toObject(FeaturedDeal.class).withDocId(docID);
                            if (doc.getOldIndex() == doc.getNewIndex()) {
                                // Item changed but remained in same position
                                featuredDeals.set(doc.getOldIndex(), changedModel);
                                featuredDealAdapter.notifyItemChanged(doc.getOldIndex());
                            } else {
                                // Item changed and changed position
                                featuredDeals.remove(doc.getOldIndex());
                                featuredDeals.add(doc.getNewIndex(), changedModel);
                                featuredDealAdapter.notifyItemMoved(doc.getOldIndex(), doc.getNewIndex());
                            }
                        } else if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED) {
                            // remove
                            featuredDeals.remove(doc.getOldIndex());
                            featuredDealAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(doc.getOldIndex());
                        }
                    }
                }

        });
```

App is Crashing and Giving this error into the Logcat:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.getDocumentChanges()' on a null object reference at com.example.info.lootbox.Fragments.HomeFragment$9.onEvent(HomeFragment.java:313)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
assert documentSnapshots != null;
```

and add this check instead of assert in your listener:

```
if (e != null) {
  Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e);
  return;
}
```

You should return in the listener if there is an error. The error specifies that there is no data in snapshot.

Comment: .orderBy("priority", Query.Direction.ASCENDING) is not working. if i am putting this line of code my app is not updating data on real-time basis when i make changes into document filed. i have to close my app and start it again to see those changes. and if i remove this line of code my app works fine. and also update data on real-time basis when changes are made to database. but i also want to filter data by orderBy

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first that there is any data available in the snapshot or not . so check like this .

```
mFirestore.collection("FeaturedDeal").whereEqualTo("title","Amazon India").limit(10).orderBy("priority", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error : " + e.getMessage());
                   return;
                }else if ( documentSnapshots != null) {

                 for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                        if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                            String doc_id = doc.getDocument().getId();
                            FeaturedDeal featuredDeal = 
            doc.getDocument().toObject(FeaturedDeal.class).withDocId(doc_id);
                            featuredDeals.add(featuredDeal);
                            featuredDealAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED) {
                            String docID = doc.getDocument().getId();
                            FeaturedDeal changedModel = 
            doc.getDocument().toObject(FeaturedDeal.class).withDocId(docID);
                            if (doc.getOldIndex() == doc.getNewIndex()) {
                                // Item changed but remained in same position
                                featuredDeals.set(doc.getOldIndex(), changedModel);
                                featuredDealAdapter.notifyItemChanged(doc.getOldIndex());
                            } else {
                                // Item changed and changed position
                                featuredDeals.remove(doc.getOldIndex());
                                featuredDeals.add(doc.getNewIndex(), changedModel);
                                featuredDealAdapter.notifyItemMoved(doc.getOldIndex(), doc.getNewIndex());
                            }
                        } else if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED) {
                            // remove
                            featuredDeals.remove(doc.getOldIndex());
                            featuredDealAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(doc.getOldIndex());
                        }
                    }
                }

           }

        });
```

Comment: .orderBy("priority", Query.Direction.ASCENDING) is not working. if i am putting this line of code my app is not updating data on real-time basis when i make changes into document filed. i have to close my app and start it again to see those changes. and if i remove this line of code my app works fine. and also update data on real-time basis when changes are made to database. but i also want to filter data by orderBy